# Multiple Regex not using level

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I want to separate the strings one by one and become row.
I've query its only get the arithmetic operator not for the number

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('141*47+2/5','[^0-9]+| [0-9]+',1,LEVEL) AS FORMULA
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('141*47+2/5','[^0-9]+| [0-9]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
```

### input

```
141*47+2/5
```

the result :

```
*
--
+
--
/
```

my expectation :

```
141
--
*
--
47
---
+
--
2
--
/
--
5
```

Comment: can your string contain negative numbers and brackets? (e.g. `'(-1+10)*5'`). If so, what should the output look like? Does the minus go on a separate line, even though it's part of the number? And what about a number like `1.3e2`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('141*47+2/5','[^0-9]+| [0-9]+',1,LEVEL) AS FORMULA
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('141*47+2/5','[^0-9]+| [0-9]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('141*47+2/5','[0-9]+',1,LEVEL) AS FORMULA
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('141*47+2/5','[0-9]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
```

I using this query its work, but its slow.

Comment: I don't wont using UNION, any other way ?

Comment: It should be `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` . `UNION` tries to combine common elements into one, which is not necessary in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT '141*47+2/5' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT '100*(10 + 2)' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT '-1*5+2/6' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT '(10+2)*5' str FROM dual)
SELECT str,
       regexp_substr(str, '([[:digit:]]+|[\*/+-\(\)]{1})', 1, LEVEL) sub_str
FROM   sample_data
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(str, '([[:digit:]]+|[\*/+-\(\)]{1})', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
           AND PRIOR str = str
           AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL;

STR          SUB_STR
------------ ------------
(10+2)*5     (
(10+2)*5     10
(10+2)*5     +
(10+2)*5     2
(10+2)*5     )
(10+2)*5     *
(10+2)*5     5
-1*5+2/6     -
-1*5+2/6     1
-1*5+2/6     *
-1*5+2/6     5
-1*5+2/6     +
-1*5+2/6     2
-1*5+2/6     /
-1*5+2/6     6
100*(10 + 2) 100
100*(10 + 2) *
100*(10 + 2) (
100*(10 + 2) 10
100*(10 + 2) +
100*(10 + 2) 2
100*(10 + 2) )
141*47+2/5   141
141*47+2/5   *
141*47+2/5   47
141*47+2/5   +
141*47+2/5   2
141*47+2/5   /
141*47+2/5   5
```

N.B. I have not accounted for numbers in scientific format (e.g. 1.3e+2, 2.6e-5), and I have assumed that negative numbers should have the minus sign on a separate line.